# QListView not displaying in Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to display a very simple and short list of countries using `QStringListModel` and `QListView`. But when I compile it, I get a blank window.

This is the code for my class :

```
#include "FenPrincipale.h"

FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale()
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QStringList listePays;
    listePays << "France" << "Espagne" << "Italie" << "Portugal" << "Suisse";
    QStringListModel *modele = new QStringListModel(listePays);

    QListView *vue = new QListView;
    vue->setModel(modele);
    layout->addWidget(vue);

    setLayout(layout);
}
```

The header :

```
#ifndef FENPRINCIPALE_H
#define FENPRINCIPALE_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStringListModel>

class FenPrincipale : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FenPrincipale();
};

#endif // FENPRINCIPALE_H
```

The main :

```
#include "FenPrincipale.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FenPrincipale w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The `pro` file :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = utilisationModeleSimple
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        FenPrincipale.cpp

HEADERS  += FenPrincipale.h

FORMS    += FenPrincipale.ui
```

I am currently using Qt Creator 3.3.0 based on Qt 5.4.0 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit); OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `QMainWindow`, then you need to set your widget as central: [`QMainWindow::​setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget). There are good samples in Qt documentation.

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale()
{
    QStringList listePays;
    listePays << "France" << "Espagne" << "Italie" << "Portugal" << "Suisse";
    QStringListModel *modele = new QStringListModel(listePays);

    QListView *vue = new QListView;
    vue->setModel(modele);

    setCentralWidget( vue );
}
```

If you don't need `QMainWindow` functionality, then simply interhit `QWidget` instead of `QMainWindow` - and your code will work.